# How can I implement stop and start using $interval service

Tags: angularjs

I use `$interval` in my project.

here is code from my controller:

```
self.timer = $interval(function () {
        checkUpdate();
    }, 10000, false);

function checkUpdate() {
    sensorsDataServise.checkForUpdate("2012-10-04T16:10:00")
    .then(function (result) {
        if (result.status == '200') {
            //here to stop the $interval
            return result.data;
        }
    });
}

function modalClosed() {
    //here to start $interval
}
```

I need to stop and start `$interval` service.

I try to use this `$interval.cancel(self.timer)` in `checkUpdate` function and

I try to use this `$interval.start(self.timer)` in `modalClosed` function.

But I get error:

> $interval.cancel and $interval.start is not a function.

How can I implement stop and start using `$interval` service.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance... What is '$interval'?

Comment: @MarcoS: `$interval` is an angular js defined `setInterval` method which runs the specific lines of code for after some interval/delay .https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

Comment: Thanks, sorry! I did not know about it... :-(

Comment: `$interval` does have a `.cancel` method which cancels the current Timer but there is no method called `start`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say : RTFM -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval

More precisely : to start you don't need .start just do

```
var stopHandler = $interval(myFn);
```

To stop do :

```
$interval.cancel(stopHandler);
```

The fact that $interval.cancel seems to not be defined in your sample code may be due to a injection problem, show us your controller/service definition that goes along with the code you showed us

Comment: And how do I start it again after canceling?

Comment: @Michael, you just have to start a new interval

Answer (score 1):

`$interval` does have a `.cancel` method which cancels the current Timer but there is no method called `start`.

to start a timer, you just need to run the `$internal` inside the `modalClosed` and clear the same timer inside `checkUpdate()`.

*Note:Make sure `ModalClosed()` function is executed first and then `checkUpdate()` else `self.timer` object will be undefined.*

**JS CODE:**

```
var self = this;

function checkUpdate() {
        sensorsDataServise.checkForUpdate("2012-10-04T16:10:00")
       .then(function (result) {
           if (result.status == '200') {
              //here to stop the $interval
              $internal.cancel(self.timer);
               return result.data;
           }
       });
    }



function modalClosed () {
   //here to start $interval
   self.timer = $interval(function () { checkUpdate(); }, 10000, false);
}
```

Comment: And how can I fire interval from template?

I try use this :

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="list.timer;">close</button> 

But it not works

Comment: yo call from template, you just need to call the `$interval` to start the timer, in your case you need to call `modalClosed()`